# MBStyle in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, style

I have SLD style and I would like to transform it to MBstyle in GeoServer. I have no idea how set the stroke-width in MBStyle for a polygon that also has a fill?

My SLD style:

```
         <Rule>
           <Name>polygon1</Name>
           <Title>polygon1</Title     
           <PolygonSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
             <Fill>
               <CssParameter name="fill">#ce4c00</CssParameter>
             </Fill>
             <Stroke>
               <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
               <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter>
             </Stroke>
           </PolygonSymbolizer>
         </Rule>
```

Now, I have:

{
"version": 8,
"name": "polygon1",
"layers": [
{
"id": "polygon1",
"type": "fill",
"paint": {
"fill-color": "#ce4c00",
"fill-outline-color": "#000000"
}
}

]
}

But I can't find any information how to do: width of 'outline'

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: sorry, already edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GeoServer documentation https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/styling/mbstyle/cookbook/polygons.html has an example about fill-outline with a notice

> This example is similar to the Simple polygon example above, with the
> addition of fill-outline paint parameter (line 9). Line 9 also sets
> the color of stroke to white ('#FFFFFF'), the "fill-outline-color" can
> only be 1 pixel, a limitation of MBStyle.

The MapBox style specification indeed defines only "fill-outline-color" but no way for setting the width. Obviously it is impossible. A workaround is make a separate line layer from the boundary and set the width with https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-line-line-width.